# Break Path into multiple Paths

Tags: php

I have the following path for example:

```
/Test1/Test2/Test3
```

Sometimes this path can be for example:

```
/Test1/Test2/Test3/Test4/Test5 and so on...
```

What I would like to do is take this unknown path and translate it into sections which will ultimately result in a navigation URL such as:

```
/Test1
/Test1/Test2
/Test1/Test2/Test3
and so on...
```

It's difficult to supply you with any code examples because many of the things I have attempted have resulted in no good results.

I assume I need to explode() the path using / as the delimiter and then splice it together somehow. I'm really at a loss here.

Does anyone have any suggestions I can try?

Comment: explode on `/` and `implode` each time one more object from the array using `array_slice`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$path = '/Test1/Test2/Test3/Test4/Test5';

$explode = explode('/', $path);

$count = count($explode);

$res = '';
for($i = 1; $i < $count; $i++) {
    echo $res .= '/' . $explode[$i];
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

Returns:

```
/Test1
/Test1/Test2
/Test1/Test2/Test3
/Test1/Test2/Test3/Test4
/Test1/Test2/Test3/Test4/Test5
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you get your array segments:

```
$path = '/Test1/Test2/Test3/Test4/Test5'; // or whatever your path is
$segments = explode('/', ltrim('/',$path));
```

If I understand you, then what you want to do is to build an array that is like

```
Array(
  [0] => '/Test1'
  [1] => '/Test1/Test2'
  ...
)
```

So you could just loop through your array and build up this new array

```
$paths_from_segments = array();
$segment_count = count($sgements);
$path_string = '';
foreach($sgement as $segment) {
    $path_string .= '/' . $segment;
    $paths_from_segments[] = $path_string;
}
var_dump($paths_from_segments);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you mean by "splice it together", but from the sounds of it you're looking for PHP's [`implode()`](https://www.php.net/function.implode), which is `explode()` in reverse.

```
explode("/", "test1/test2");

// result:
// Array
// (
//     [0] => test1
//     [1] => test2
// )

implode("/", Array("test1", "test2"));

// result:
// "test1/test2"
```